# xCode 4.6 - Missing Required Architecture armv6

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to send my binary to Apple (via Application Loader) for App store approval.  However, every time I send my .zip file I get the error "application is missing a required architecture.  At least one of the following architecture(s) must be present: armv6."

Here are my Build Settings:

[image]

My iOS Deployment Target is 4.3.

After making these setting changes I do Product -> Build For -> Archiving.  Open the .app file under the Products folder and do the "compress" action to create the .zip file.

When I load said .zip file in Application Loader it still gives me the error.  These Architecture settings are for both my Project and my Target.

Any ideas?

Comment: in Architectures you have to include armv7s for iPhone 5

Comment: You don't have to include the `ARMv7s` for the iPhone 5, if you have a library that does not include support fro the `ARMv7s` you can remove support for the `ARMv7s` and you app wil run fine on the iPhone 5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Xcode 4.* with the iOS 6 SDk does include support voor ARMv6 any more.

So if you want to build against iOS SDK 6.0 you will have to drop support for the ARMv6.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I'm not familiar with xCode/Apple stuff at all and have to do this for the company I work for.  Can I change my Base SDK to a lower version (say iOS 4.3) and it work ok you think?

Comment: No, this will not work. If you installed the any Xcode version that comes with the iOS 6 SDK you can't build for ARMv6. You will need an Xcode version with the iOS 5 SDK, problem here is that you can then not target the iPhone 5 larger screen. So either support old devices or support new device, the choice is yours.

Answer (score 0):

if this change not solved your problem kindly check your version of application loader might be you are using old xcode application loader. try with new one application loader